RPi5 ubuntu 24.04 / NVMe SSD / failed install and graphics acceleration
I installed several RPi5 (8Go RAM) with SSD on NVMe BASE (PIM699 by Pimoroni) and on the last installation I made (beginning on December 2024 the 16th), it fails and I got a green screen.
The procedure I followed, was to have a Raspbian installed on a SD card and from the rpi-imager of the Raspbian install the Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 LTS on the NVMe SSD.
On the last install, I experienced some changes: rpi-imager stopped asking me for login/password, local info, timezone, etc.
And it failed : I got a green screen, I could launch a terminal but as I had no login/password, I could not go further.
I found a solution:

install the Ubuntu Server 24.04 LTS
I could enter the login/password, local, etc. info from the rpi-imager
from the terminal of the ubuntu server, I installed ubuntu-desktop:

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop -y

Then I could boot in and get the standard gnome window manager interface.
However when I launched firefox or chromium, I clearly got no gpu acceleration and the web browser windows where frozen blank.
I could use chromium but by using the option ''disable-gpu''
chromium --disable-gpu

I was wondering if there was a graphics driver problem on the last ubuntu desktop install, and if it was the reason I had a green screen earlier.
I tested the graphics card with the following tools and below are the results I got:
lsmod | grep -i v3d

I got:
v3d                   131072  25
gpu_sched              61440  1 v3d
drm_shmem_helper       24576  1 v3d

sudo dmesg | grep -i v3d

I got:
[    8.071241] [drm] Initialized v3d 1.0.0 20180419 for 1002000000.v3d on minor 0

Saying that the driver v3d was initialized
I did some performance tests with ''glmark2'' and I got a score of 320, which is not great but not too bad.
I dit a couple of other tests:
ls /dev/dri

Output:
by-path  card0  card1  renderD128

The only weird thing is when I check GPU Memory Allocation:
sudo vcgencmd get_mem gpu

I got:
gpu=8M

Even if with ''raspi-config'' I setup gpu memory to be 256M with ''Performance Options > GPU Memory > 256M''
So I am out of ideas to fix web browsers (at least) and to understand what went wrong with the install.
For the record, I eliminated any hardware problem, because with the Raspbian on SDCard, everything worked smoothly and well.
And why am-I insisting to setup Ubuntu on a Raspberry Pi 5 ? I need to use the RPi5 as ROS2 platforms and ROS2 is historically (and thus well) supported for Ubuntu.

Your question is unclear, as is what you have actually done. If you are attempting to use the imager to preconfigure Ubuntu it won't work. You will need to setup manually as a normal Ubuntu installation.
